# Laggy flutter animations in screen using WebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a screen mostly made of webview and now I want to do some animation on top of the page, but as it turns out this is very very slow and laggy for some reason.
My code structure is like this:

```
AnimatedBuilder(
animation:_animationController,
builder (_,_)=>
Stack(
  children:[
    Container(color:Colors.blue),
    Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(100*_animationController.value,0)
        WebView(...)
    ),
  ]
)
```

You can reproduce this easily using any website for webview and try to do some animation on top of it like this.

I have seen that even the page transitions are laggy in my app after using this WebView.

[Video link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1nls.jpg)

Please note that the lag might not be apparent in the GIF I have posted but its there on the device for real!

Also as pointed out in comments, The lag is present in both debug and release mode.

Is there a solution of fix I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want to animate that web view as well or just a widget on top of it?

Comment: My use case is to push a new screen on to of this webview, but that is laggy as well just like this.

Comment: Well there's a diff between performance in debug and release mode. And if you dont wanna animate web view then why have you added it inside animation builder

Comment: Yes I understand this, but its the lag is present in both debug and release mode.
Just for testing I have added AnimatedBuilder, but its the same lag with page transitions as well.